# Showing which files matched a grep that is looking through all files from a collection

Tags: shell, command-line, grep

Suppose I have a collection of files like this:

```
echo -e "apple\n cherry" >> f1.txt; 
echo -e "grape\n strawberry" >> f2.txt; 
echo -e "orange\n cherry" >> f3.txt;
```

And I want to find each file that has the word "cherry" in it. I can do this:

```
ls *.txt | xargs cat | grep cherry
```

But this just returns the two lines that match from f1 and f3, without showing the "source" files, like so:

```
cherry
cherry
```

I'd like is to see the files where these matches came from---something like this:

```
f1.txt ->  cherry 
f3.txt ->  cherry
```

Is there a way to do this simply from the command line?

Comment: wait... are you doing a study on the answers you get? :^)

Comment: small world! BTW, the paper you helped us w/ got accepted at AAAI - the whole thing turned out very nicely. Here's the link: http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/WS/AAAIW11/paper/view/3983

Comment: oh - and this isn't a study - I really needed to know the answer.

Comment: thanks, going to add that to my resume!

Comment: Doesn't anyone read man pages any more? `:)` How, all these years, have you been `vi`-ing multiple files that contain a match for something? `vi $(grep -l foo *.txt)`. :)

Comment: :) Yes - in retrospect this is a pretty poor question. I think mentally I was so down my pipes/xargs/cat rabbit hole of a solution that the more obvious (and very man page accessible) approach was lost on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ echo -e "apple\n cherry" >> f1.txt; 
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ echo -e "grape\n strawberry" >> f2.txt; 
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ echo -e "orange\n cherry" >> f3.txt; 
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ grep cherry *txt
f1.txt: cherry
f3.txt: cherry
```

Comment: JC, you're awesome - thanks. SO says I need to way 11 minutes minutes to approve the answer...

Answer (score 3):

The `-l` option means that grep will print the matching filenames only, rather than the matching lines, so your task can be achieved by:

```
$ grep -l cherry *.txt
f1.txt
f3.txt
```

(Note that the `ls` and the `xargs` are unnecessary for this task, grep treats all but the first of its positional arguments as files to look through)

Answer (score 2):

Try `grep -H` to print the file name and the match.  From the man page:

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print  the  file  name for each match.  This is the default when
          there is more than one file to search.
```

I find this is useful when using `grep` with `find`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ls *.txt | xargs cat`, you get one combined stream of data, so the information of filenames is lost and can't be recovered by a subsequent `grep`.

These should work:

```
ls *.txt | xargs grep cherry
```

or even simpler:

```
grep cherry *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

grep cherry *.txt
This should do it for you